# How to change color in Drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have `ImageView` in my application, but images in this `ImageView` have white background. How I can delete this `ColorDrawable`. I need to replace White to Transparent. How I can do it programmaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not as easy to do programmaticaly but it is easy to do in an image editor. I always do it in paint.net. You can download it here: http://www.getpaint.net/download.html

This youtube video describes how to do it: https://youtu.be/cdFpS-AvNCE

It literally takes less than a minute to do and is what I have used on a lot of my projects.

Comment: I have a lot of images.

Answer (score 0):

The color you set by `ImageView.setBackgroundColor` method shows up only where the `src` image have some transparent pixels or some spaces of `ImageView` that is not covered by the `src` image because of `scaleType` And I'm not sure you want to process images in your code in order to replace back color with transparent color, So the right way to achieve that is to use some **Photo Editor** softwares to edit images before using in your app.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to [remove the background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8S0V6RqMZjs) from the original photo using a photo editor like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) ,be sure to save the file in an Android supported format that supports transparency (PNG).

Next, inside the XML layout file (or in code), put the `drawable` view itself inside a `FrameLayout`.

Finally, call `View.setBackgroundColor()` on your `FrameLayout`.